# Question about particular solutions of $y''+4xy'+Q(x)y=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we know that $$y''+4xy'+Q(x)y=0$$ 
have two solutions of the form: $y_1=u(x)$ and $y_2=xu(x)$, where $u(0)=1$. How can we determine $u(x)$ and $Q(x)$ explicitly? (This problem is extracted from: Tom Apostol Calculus II.)

If $x$ does not appear in the above equation, (i.e. just y'', y and constants) i can solve similar problems. Because in that case, i can say that if the ODE have a solution of the form $y=e^{kx}$ then the general solution is of the form $y=Ae^{k_1x}+Be^{k_2x}$, etc.

Can i do something similar for the above equation?

Any help or suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: **Hint**: The Wronskian of the two solutions is $W(y_1,y_2)=u^2$.

Comment: Thanks. But i can't use the Wronskian (not yet seen in class). Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y_2=xy_1$ is a solution to $y''+4xy'+Q(x)y=0$, so
$$
(xy_1)''+4x(xy_1)'+Q(x)(xy_1)=0
$$
Equivalently :
$
2y_1'+xy_1''+4x(y_1+xy_1')+Q(x)xy_1=0
$,
or
$$
2y_1'+4xy_1+x\underbrace{(y_1''+4xy_1'+Q(x)y_1)}_{0}=0
$$
where we used that $y_1$ is also a solution to the same differential equation. Thus
$u'=-2xu$ and $u(0)=0$ thus $u(x)=e^{-x^2}$, Now Recalling that $u=y_1$ is a solution to the proposed equation allows us to determine $Q$,
hence $Q(x)=2+4x^2$.